# PHP Filter Input Array

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
if(isset(filter_input_array(input_post)
```

Also the reason why im using Filter input array is because $_POST doesn't even work anymore not on netbeans anyway.

My localHost hits me back with a :

Warning: Use of undefined constant input_post - assumed 'input_post' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test1\Includes\signup2.inc.php on line 3

I'm pretty new to Coding and especially PHP. Im in 1st year of Uni doing course work, so dont get upset if its a silly question. But I have no idea how to fix this.

This is all I have so far

```
<?php

if(isset(filter_input_array(input_post)['signup-submit'])) {

require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $username = filter_input_array(input_post)['uid'];
    $email = filter_input_array(input_post)['mail'];
    $password = filter_input_array(input_post)['pwd'];
    $passwordRepeat = filter_input_array(input_post)['pwd-repeat'];
```

Comment: PHP variables are case sensitive `INPUT_POST`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php

Comment: Wow.. Thats all it was. Ive got a lot to learn. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering input is [fundamentally wrong](https://symcbean.blogspot.com/2017/07/validate-input-escape-output.html?m=0) (really the issue here is about PHP naming conventions).

> because $_POST doesn't even work anymore

So your workaround for a problem is no longer working. Stop trying to fix your workaround and fix the problem. PHP is primarily a scripting language for the web - if it is not handling request data something is very wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try using $_REQUEST as global var.

Comment: $_REQUEST ['field_form']